# How can I create a simple blur effect on a faceMesh in Spark AR Studio?

Tags: graphics, shader, spark-ar-studio, image-effects

I want to create a very simple AR effect that simply blurs the user's face (I'm using a faceTracker with a faceMesh that has a material blurMat applied)
but I don't really know what to do now.
I am quite fit at javascript but I never did any image manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this repository for Blur, sharpen, edge-detection, and convolution patches

https://github.com/positlabs/spark-convolution-patch